# Is iPhone 6 and 6 Plus support is compulsory on Apple iTunes to submit my application

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, appstore-approval, iphone-6-plus

i have my app uploaded on iTunes which was supporting 3.5 and 4 inch, but now i have done some changes which has been done on Xcode 7. So i just want to know that is this compulsory to add iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus Splash Screen. I don't want to support my app for iPhone 6 and 6 plus. if anyone install on iPhone 6 then it will have same resolution as iPhone 5s.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about Apple App Store submission and not a programming question.

Comment: ur app should support all kinds of iphones!!!!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is No. You don't need to support iphone 6 and 6p if you don't want to. Your app will get approved.

Your app will scale up on 6 & 6p as long as your app supports 4in (iphone 5) which you are doing.

For a universal app, minimum requirement for screen sizes is

- iphone 4
- iphone 5
- ipad 2

Comment: Thanks Sam , you save my life.